# Is there any extension for visual studio to optimize C++ code unit testing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

In C# .Net there is nice `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` framework that is integrated into IDE. Is there any extension for visual studio (2012 or 2013) that would do similar IDE test framework integration (for boost.test or any onter C++ testing framework)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the CppUnitTestFramework, look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694604.aspx

It is integrated in the IDE and comes with a code coverage tool which is quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Boost Unit Test Adapter](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5f4ae1bd-b769-410e-8238-fb30beda987f) for VS2012 (but not VS2013).